# How to extract part of URL from curl response in bash script?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am trying to extract a part of `URL` returned in the `curl` response in a `bash` script. This will be used in the later stages of the script.

The curl response has this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/1234/text/111?x=999988
```

Now, I would like to extract `text/111?x=999988` from it. Also, I want to store only the number `111` in a variable.
I am trying to do this with

```
#!/bin/bash

sample_link="https://www.example.com/1234/text/111?x=999988"
sample_extract=${sample_link##*/}
echo "$sample_extract"
```

But this gives me only `111?x=999988`

Can anyone please let me know what am I missing and how to resolve it?

P.S: please let me know if any info is missing

Answer (score 5):

With `GNU` `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP 'https://[^/]+/\d+/\K.*' <<< 'https://www.example.com/1234/text/111?x=999988'
text/111?x=999988
```

Or

With `Perl`:

```
$ perl -nE 'say $& if m@https://[^/]+/\d+/\K.*@' <<< 'https://www.example.com/1234/text/111?x=999988'a
text/111?x=999988a
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `https://` | 'https://' |
| `[^/]+` | any character except: `/` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `/` | / |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `/` | / |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

---

```
$ grep -oP 'https://[^/]+/\d+/\w+/\K\d+' <<< 'https://www.example.com/1234/text/111?x=999988'
111
```

or

```
$ perl -nE 'say $& if m@https://[^/]+/\d+/\w+/\K\d+' <<< 'https://www.example.com/1234/text/111?x=999988'a
111
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `https://` | 'https://' |
| `[^/]+` | any character except: `/` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `/` | / |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `/` | / |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `/` | / |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

---

To assign to variable, I think you know how to do it =) (your original post show how to do so)

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to extract part of the URL but then you continue by saying that you only want part of that stored in a variable.

Extracting part of a value and doing nothing with it doesn't add any value, unless you meant you want to output it:

```
response='https://www.example.com/1234/text/111?x=999988'
echo "tail is $(grep -o '[^/]*/[^/]*?.*' <<<"$response")"
```

Output

```
tail is text/111?x=999988
```

To get the last part into a variable:

```
response='https://www.example.com/1234/text/111?x=999988'
last=${response%\?*}
last=${last##*/}
echo "last is $last"
```

Output

```
last is 111
```